# DX11 Updating Shared Textures

Tags: multithreading, graphics, directx, directx-11

I have a shared DX11 texture that is being used with 2 different devices in separate threads.

Thread1 (operating on device 1): Called every frame and updates the shared texture

Thread2(operating on device2): Consumes the shared texture by copying it to another texture. Frequency is much lesser than thread 1.

According to MSDN "If a shared texture is updated on one device ID3D11DeviceContext::Flush must be called on that device."

However calling flush on thread1 every frame is very expensive and we see a massive performance hit. We can't flush device 1 on thread 2, because a device context is not thread safe.

Is there a way to efficiently make the shared texture update when threads 2 needs to consume it?

Thanks for your help! MSDN is not very helpful when dealing with shared textures.
*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0):

In order to synchronize the access to the shared resource between two threads (or interprocess) you can use IDXGIKeyedMutex. It is described here in details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554(v=vs.85).aspx#dxgi_1.1_synchronized_shared_surfaces

You can check the sample code provided as well although they show only resource sharing between two DX10 devices. It is the same for DX11 devices. 
The essential part is to QueryInterface the shared texture for IDXGIResource first and then for IDXGIKeyedMutex. After that you use the mutex for synchronization by using AcquireSync and ReleaseSync functions.

Comment: Unfortunately keyed mutexes don't work for me because there is no defined order for which thread should run first. Both threads can be called at random intervals which makes keyed mutexes unsuitable for this scenario

Comment: @Sid I believe you can simply use same key for both thread in that case.